# Scorm Offline Data Tracking to understand data format of quiz result

Tags: javascript, flash, scorm

I am literally new to scorm and LMS. In most simple form I do need to store quiz result(all questions result as he/she answers) in session or something like that , so that when user goes online it syncs with database by making proper api calls.I came to know that there are some packages like http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/tin-can-api-in-scorm-engine/ , but I guess they are paid. So I just need to know how to track data in console or something like that , when user answer question one by one. I am not able to do because scorm package is just loading flash player and everything happens there.